# Only 10% of my site are indexed

Tags: google-search-console, url, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

I'm newbie in Google Webmaster Tools and I use sitemap.xml to submit urls.
The problem is that I've submitted 150 urls and only 17 are indexed! Is that a problem or they will be indexed later?

Comment: Your site isn't being indexed because you're just stealing content from other sites and reposting it on yours. Search engines don't index pages with low quality or duplicate content because they're of little value to users. Google and other search engines make no secret of this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a new site, give it some time.

You can review for any crawl errors in Webmaster Tools > Health > Crawl Errors to see if there are any problems with the site preventing Google from crawling.

If the content on these other pages is not unique Google may choose not to include it in the index, too.

Comment: Thank you very much.. i just add my sites to google webmaster one week ago

Comment: But the status is never chnaged for 3 days

Comment: It can take longer than three days don't worry. Best advice is keep an eye on your Webmaster account for any problems - if there are no errors it will get indexed whenever Google feels like it. :)

Comment: I agree my website content is not unique but i remark that among of 174 url submitted via sitemaps only 17 were indexed and no page indexed yet zero

Comment: Google may not even have crawled the site yet, let alone placed it in the index. I'd say give it another week at least.

Comment: ROTFL 3 days? This whole question is a duplicate of hundreds of others that have been asked here every year. They boil down to "I've just put up my site, it's been less than a week, why hasn't Google indexed 100% of it?" The answer? Lack of incoming links, low value of content and insufficient time for Google to establish that the content has relevance and authoritative websites Google knows about recognize that it's content actually rates above low value and therefore should be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this too, it puzzled me for ages but I think I've found what's causing it. As Gabriel said Google may not chose to include those pages into the index because of content being either not unique, not enough content or not relevant enough.

If you look under Webmaster Tools > Health > Index Status > Advanced you can see how many pages Google looked at and its "Total Indexed" amount and also its "Not Selected" amount.

The best way I've found for it to index your pages is to build links, either to the site in general or particular pages that aren't indexed; it doesn't have to be tons of links but just a couple tends to make Google see those pages as slightly more authoritative .

Comment: Thanks but all my pages are linked with a header,i'm using drupal7 with metatag and page title